# При компиляции Caffe возникает ошибка “libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `cv::imread(cv::String const&, int)'”

Tags: python

Видел много советов, но ни один не помогает.
Пытался добавить `opencv_imgcodecs` в **Makefile**, использовать `cmake` вместо make и т.д.

**Makefile.config**

```
CPU_ONLY := 1
OPENCV_VERSION := 3
CUSTOM_CXX := g++
CUDA_DIR := /usr/local/cuda
CUDA_ARCH := -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_20 \
        -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_21 \
        -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 \
        -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 \
        -gencode arch=compute_50,code=sm_50 \
        -gencode arch=compute_52,code=sm_52 \
        -gencode arch=compute_60,code=sm_60 \
        -gencode arch=compute_61,code=sm_61 \
        -gencode arch=compute_61,code=compute_61

BLAS := atlas
PYTHON_INCLUDE := /usr/include/python2.7 \
        /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include
PYTHON_LIB := /usr/lib
INCLUDE_DIRS := $(PYTHON_INCLUDE) /usr/local/include /usr/include/hdf5/serial
LIBRARY_DIRS := $(PYTHON_LIB) /usr/local/lib /usr/lib /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hdf5/serial
BUILD_DIR := build
DISTRIBUTE_DIR := distribute
TEST_GPUID := 0
Q ?= @
```

когда выполняю `make all`, возникает следующая ошибка:

```
CXX/LD -o .build_release/tools/extract_features.bin
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `cv::imread(cv::String const&, int)'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `cv::String::allocate(unsigned long)'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `cv::String::deallocate()'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `cv::imencode(cv::String const&, cv::_InputArray const&, std::vector<unsigned char, std::allocator<unsigned char> >&, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:635: recipe for target '.build_release/tools/extract_features.bin' failed
make: *** [.build_release/tools/extract_features.bin] Error 1
```

Ubuntu 18.04.
Последний туториал, которым руководствовался [Этот](https://gist.github.com/nikitametha/c54e1abecff7ab53896270509da80215)
Судя по выводу:

```
AR -o .build_release/lib/libcaffe.a
LD -o .build_release/lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0
CXX tools/extract_features.cpp
CXX/LD -o .build_release/tools/extract_features.bin
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `cv::imread(cv::String const&, int)'
```

получается, что у нас собирается динамическая библиотека `libcaffe.so` и сразу же после мы используем ее для взаимойдействия с `extract_features.bin`. Если бы узнать из чего компилится `libcaffe.so`, быть может можно было бы включить в какой либо из исходных файлов подключение OpenCV.
Но как определить исходные файлы для создания `libcaffe.so` не могу понять.
Пробовал смотреть в Makefile, ощущение, словно он обфусцирован, ничего не понятно.

Comment: В каком направлении двигаться хотя бы, чтобы решить проблему?

Comment: а как вы opencv устанавливали?